# Synchronized Overridden methods: Intrinsic Locks acquiring order for parent and child classes

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Which locks are held in overridden non-static synchronized methods.
Please provide the sequence in which the monitor locks of base-class and sub-class are acquired and released so that it explains the benefit of **Reentrancy** in java. It would be great if the sequences can be explained with the help of owning thread and acquisition count that JVM maintains to implement reentrancy.

```
public class Widget {
    public synchronized void doSomething() {
    }
}

public class LoggingWidget extends Widget {
    public synchronized void doSomething() {
        super.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Please note that this question is specifically asked for the explanation of implicit reentrant locks, so pls dont mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: Since you already name “reentrancy” I assume that you already know that it is the same lock that is just acquired twice. Then there is only one possible order. The order of program execution. Nothing else would ever make sense. Not that it matters in which “order” a single counter is incremented…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each **object** has an associated monitor. When a synchronized instance method is called on an object, the monitor associated with this object needs to be held by the calling thread.

The class of the object is irrelevant.

Comment: if a thread is executing doSomething() in the subclass, in the next line it will try to acquire the monitor of the super-class. And the super-class doSomething() will also try to acquire the lock on itself. So, which one happens first?

Comment: No. doSomething() is an **instance** method. So it's invoked on the object. And there is a single object involved, which is an instance of the subclass and also an instance of the superclass.